# KNN performance measures

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I have a college project which is a movie recommendation system using item-based collaborative filtering. I used the KNN algorithm and it worked properly but, as a mandatory requirement, I am asked to visualize any performance metrics such as accuracy, precision, or recall while this algorithm is un unsupervised learning method. I searched a lot but I got nothing. What can I do?

```
# MODEL TRAINING AND TESTING
model = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine',algorithm='brute',n_neighbors=20,n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(movie_user_matrix_sparse)
movie_input = input('Enter the movie name: ')

def find_movie():
    ratio = 50
    founded_movie_id = 0
    for index, name in dict.items():
        result_ratio = fuzz.ratio(name.lower(), movie_input.lower())
        if result_ratio >= ratio:
            ratio = result_ratio
            founded_movie_id = index
    if founded_movie_id == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return founded_movie_id

indeces_list = []
result = find_movie()
if result == -1:
    print('The movie title you entered does not exist!')
else:
    indeces_list = model.kneighbors(movie_user_matrix_sparse[result], n_neighbors=11, return_distance=False)

final_indeces_list = []
for i in range(1,indeces_list.shape[1]):
    final_indeces_list.append(int(indeces_list[0][i]))
print('The top 10 similar movies: \n')
for i in range(len(final_indeces_list)):
    key = final_indeces_list[i]
    #print(key)
    if key in dict.keys():
        print(dict[key])
    else:
        print('It does not exist!')
```

Comment: Without ground truth data, I doubt that these measures are possible.

Comment: I think so, too. But unfortunately, the college insists on that. Or I lose grades.